# File is not showing local language after downloading

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, encoding, decode

I have an application which is developed with node.js and hosted on heroku. We are generating a pdf on the node.js server and sending the stream to frontend, so that the users can download the file.

When i am trying it on the localhost, i am able to see proper content in the file. But when i host the node.js code on heroku and try the same, the file is not showing local language(telugu, an indian language) in the pdf. Below is the screenshot of the file i am getting.

[image]

The below code is the frontend code which will hit the server api and get the file content from server

```
const response = await axios.post(
          '/reports/pdf',
          { tests: this.tests },
          { responseType: 'blob' },
        );
        window.console.log(response);
        if (response) {
          this.createAndDownloadBlobFile(response, 'tests');
        }
```

The below code is to download the file. This function is called in the above code after getting the response.

```
createAndDownloadBlobFile(body, filename, extension = 'pdf') {
      const blob = new Blob([body]);
      const fileName = `${filename}.${extension}`;
      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
        // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
      } else {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
        if (link.download !== undefined) {
          const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
          link.setAttribute('href', url);
          link.setAttribute('download', fileName);
          link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
          document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
      }
    },
```

The node.js code is as below

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pdf
        .create(document, options)
        .then((res) => {
          var content = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, '../utils/output.pdf'));
          resolve(content);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
```

I tried few different ways by changing the response format to base64 and changing the data format. But still no use. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Your localhost knows your OS language preference. Heroku has no idea and defaults to English. Your first issue is how to send preferred language to server and react accordingly there

Comment: How to send or config the preferred language on server? And is there a way to make it work with some of the encoding formats?

Comment: Is this a missing / wrong font issue or have things actually been encoded incorrectly (like with substitution characters)?

Comment: As u can see in the attached image, content is there, but not showing properly.